# CloudKit Dashboard keeps showing log in screen

Tags: redirect, authentication, dashboard, cloudkit

Has anyone else experienced an issue where the CloudKit Dashboard will rarely log in but most of the time redirect the page back to the log in screen after you've correctly typed in all the credentials?

I can't seem to find anything on the web about it, except for this post on the Apple developer forums:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25947

I'm running a late 2011 MBP with OSX Yosemite, not sure if that will help. I've tried both Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, please see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: open a private browsing window and try again!

Answer (score 4):

Try using Safari. I was having this problem with mozilla firefox.